# Detect a specific pattern inside a url /us-en/ to something else

Tags: regex, .htaccess, directive

I'm looking for a way to replace a part in a url with another part.

Here is the url:

http://localhost:8888/sa-ar/product-list.html?category=154

I want to replace this part /sa-ar/ with /web/

knowing that /sa-ar/ may change dynamically to any other country and language something like /us-en/ etc.

what is the correct regex to be able to detect the pattern /sa-ar/

This is what I have achieved so far `\/(\S{2}-\S{2})\/` Which works except when applied to .htaccess it wouldn't

Comment: http://localhost:8888/sa-ar/product-list.html?category=154

Comment: But answer below will redirect to `http://localhost:8888/web/product-list.html?category=154` so clients will only see later URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/(.+) /web/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm planning to use the regex in htaccess not in php, but can I ask why the hashes?

Comment: @Faisal Ok. You had a PHP tag on your post. I have updated. The hashes are because you can use any characters to define the regex, and sometimes in PHP they are used instead of slashes to make it more readable if there are slashes already in the regex itself.